# SDL failure to find video device when statically linked

Tags: c, sdl-2

When I set the -static flag in LDFLAGS, an SDL project fails to run, with an error of

```
sdl: No available video device
sdl: No available video device
```

Otherwise, it works fine. I've tried forcing linkage against libxcb, libx11, and more, but it still fails to run, and works fine when dynamically linked. What gives?

Pictures:

[SDL2 working fine when not statically linked.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSJ1G.png)

[SDL2 not working when statically linked.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tByt4.png)

Comment: What OS/distro are you using? Some libraries do _not_ work with [or provide] a static version. On my distro (linux/fedora) it does _not_ provide a static (e.g. `.a`) library for SDL2. In some cases, the `.a` version has limited capability. With a `.so`, it can use `dlopen` et. al. to open other "driver" libraries dynamically or specify them in the `.so` itself. The `.a` may not be able to do that (i.e. you'd have to know which extra libs are needed and explicitly mention them in the build).

Comment: From your links [which you should _not_ do on SO], you're trying to create `piano.rom`. I presume this means you're trying to create a ROM image??? Otherwise, what is the utility of trying for _force_ a static library? It's fine for system utils like `/usr/sbin/sln` that usually have simple lib requirements. However, SDL2 is actually _multiple_ libs and they're usually too large to statically link. Also, if you statically link, and the SDL2 libs are updated to fix bugs, your program will _not_ [automatically] get the benefit of the fixes [without rebuild/relink].

Comment: Hi! Piano.rom is unrelated to the SDL - i'm trying to build a static version of an emulator. I use KISS linux, which *does* carry the .a for SDL2. I have tried to force X11 library linking, which still fails...

Sorry about the links! I didn't know that.